# Text input in fortran cases?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

Im writing a piece of code in fortran:

```
write(*,*) "What do you want to do?"
      read(*,*) question
      select case(question)
      case(1)
      call sleep (1)
      goto 10 (returns at the beginning)
      case default
      write(*,*) "Ok, then good job :)"
      write(*,*) "I exit in 3 seconds..."
      call sleep (1)
      write(*,*) "I exit in 2 seconds.."
      call sleep (1)
      write(*,*) "I exit in 1 seconds."
      call sleep (2)
      goto 20 (kills the program)
```

Instead of "1" and "2" I'd like to use "Yes" and "No"
How can I do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example that uses a string ("Title") in the select/case block:

https://pages.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs201/NOTES/chap03/select.html

```
CHARACTER(LEN=4) :: Title
INTEGER          :: DrMD = 0, PhD = 0, MS = 0, BS = 0, Others = 0

SELECT CASE (Title)
   CASE ("DrMD")
      DrMD = DrMD + 1
   CASE ("PhD")
      PhD = PhD + 1
   CASE ("MS")
      MS = MS + 1
   CASE ("BS")
      BS = BS + 1
   CASE DEFAULT
      Others = Others + 1
END SELECT
```